# Vagrant and gradle continuous build

Tags: gradle, vagrant

I've got spring gradle project deployed on vagrant machine. This is my `Vangrantifle`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.12"
  config.vm.hostname = "springboot"

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-scripts/utils.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-scripts/java.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-scripts/sdkman.sh", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-scripts/springboot.sh", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-scripts/gradle.sh", privileged: false

end
```

When I try to run continuous build using `gradle build -t`  it works correctly when there are changes in source code done **inside** box, for example when I edit java files using nano.

My problem occurs when I try to modify java files in **host** by shared folders. Gradle seems to not notice any changes and it's not rebuilding project.

How can I fix this? I could of course just `touch` files on vagrant box, but it would be not very convenient.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'm using a different language and different frameworks, but the guest doesn't "recognize" that changes were made, when I made them in the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox doesn't forward inotify events to the guest system. This can be fixed with one of the plugins:

- [vagrant-notify-forwarder](https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder)
- [vagrant-fsnotify](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify)

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/453826/vagrant-shared-folder-and-file-change-events

Comment: I would add that `vagrant-notify-forwarder` is working only on Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS.